# Recursion method in c#

Tags: c#, recursion

I know how recursion method functionality works but the question is, why if the method call's itself 3 times cursor will stop 3 times too at return section?
I think it just stop once at return line!

> This method call an API to get a JSON response, on API side if response is longer than 50 items i should pass **page** parameter to API in order to get next pages data.

Code Sample:

```
private List<string> _UidResponses = new List<string>();

private void GetResponse(int iPage = 1)
{
    string _Result = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        NameValueCollection nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
        nameValues.Add("uid", _BarcodeUid);
        nameValues.Add("page", iPage.ToString());
        var newUrl = _ServiceURL + nameValues;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(newUrl);

            var postData = client.PostAsync(newUrl, new StringContent(""), new System.Threading.CancellationToken(false));
            //postData.Wait();

            var result = postData.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var _MSG = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                try
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_MSG.Result))
                    {
                        List<string> objectItems = jss.Deserialize<List<string>>(_MSG.Result);
                        if (objectItems.Count() >= _ItemCount)
                        {
                            _UidResponses.AddRange(objectItems);
                            GetResponse(++iPage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _UidResponses.AddRange(objectItems);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception rr)
                { }

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    { }

    return _Result;
}
```

Comment: "I think it just stop once at return line" - why? The method is invoked three times, so it's returning three times.

Comment: OT that `GetResponse(++iPage);` will update your "local" value of iPage (which you don't use, so no problems in *this* code). It is better to use `GetResponse(iPage+1);` to avoid unwanted side effects

Comment: This method should return `void` but at the end you have `return _Result;` which is never assigned anywhere in your code. Is this the real code? I think you chopped something

Comment: You're also using `task.Wait()` which could be deadlocking your code.

Comment: A `return` ends the *current* invocation of the method (returning to the caller), not the whole chain of recursive calls - if that's what you expected

Comment: `why if the method call's itself 3 times cursor will stop 3 times too at return section` What cursor?

Comment: Thanks to JonSkeet, HansKeﬆing, DavidG and the others. I got some advice from you and finally changed the code. as i can understand from your answers, method actually runs completely 3 times. I was thought that on method calling line, application will omit next lines and again starts from first line.

Comment: @ColinM I assume he means the "active line" in the debugger, which he's running it under.

Comment: @ColinM, I mean debugger line. As Matthew Watson said. Thanks to Matthew!

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, the fact your breakpoint on return statement is hit 3 times is just as recursion work, every return corresponds to each call (in your case 3).
There are other problems with your code, tough.

1) won't compile: your method signature is void, but you are returning a value:

```
private void GetResponse(int iPage = 1)
{
[...]
    return _Result;
}
```

also you are returning initial value of String.Empty, without any modification in your code. Just get rid of it in return statement if method is not supposed to return different value in different circumstances:

```
private void GetResponse(int iPage = 1)
{
    // string _Result = string.Empty; // <<== GET RID OF THIS LINE
    [...]
    // return _Result; // <<== Get rid as well, return; is implicit with method ending
}
```

2) postData.Result will block execution exactly like Wait(). Better go for asyncronous programming. You won't need cancellation token as well, if always passing a token that cannot be cancelled:

```
private Task GetResponseAsync(int iPage = 1) // <== Changed method name accordingly to best practices for async methods
{
   [...]
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(newUrl);

            var result = await client.PostAsync(newUrl, new StringContent(""));
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    [...]
    return _Result;
}
```

3) If you call recursively inside the HttpClient using block, the first client won't be disposed until the last execution has returned, causing potential resource leaking. Also, HttpClient performs better when reused:

```
private List<string> _UidResponses = new List<string>();
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
private Task GetResponseAsync(int iPage = 1)
{
    try
    {
        NameValueCollection nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
        nameValues.Add("uid", _BarcodeUid);
        nameValues.Add("page", iPage.ToString());
        var newUrl = _ServiceURL + nameValues;

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(newUrl);

        var result = await client.PostAsync(newUrl, new StringContent(""));

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           [...]
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    { }

}
```

4) Content.ReadAsStringAsync must be awaited as well:

```
var _MSG = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
[...]
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_MSG))
{
   List<string> objectItems = jss.Deserialize<List<string>>(_MSG);
```

5) After deserialization, since you are adding anyway the results to your list, if can be simplified:

```
_UidResponses.AddRange(objectItems);
if (objectItems.Count() >= _ItemCount)
{
   GetResponse(++iPage);
}
```

Resulting code:

```
private List<string> _UidResponses = new List<string>();
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
private Task GetResponseAsync(int iPage = 1)
{
    try
    {
        NameValueCollection nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
        nameValues.Add("uid", _BarcodeUid);
        nameValues.Add("page", iPage.ToString());
        var newUrl = _ServiceURL + nameValues;

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(newUrl);

        var result = await client.PostAsync(newUrl, new StringContent(""));

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           var _MSG = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           try
           {
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_MSG))
              {
                 List<string> objectItems = jss.Deserialize<List<string>>(_MSG);
                 _UidResponses.AddRange(objectItems);
                 if (objectItems.Count() >= _ItemCount)
                 {
                    GetResponse(++iPage);
                 }
              }
           }
           catch (Exception rr)
           { }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    { }

}
```

6) Further improvements:

- What if result.IsSuccessStatusCode == false?
- What if string.IsNullOrEmpty(_MSG) == true?
- Empty catch statements are bad practices, rethrow exception or at least log something